# android map is moving slow after many overlays added

Tags: android, dictionary

My app is growing faster every minute and more users keep joining the map. the problem is when you are just looking around on the map, it moves really slow now. just a simple click of overlay is slow  to  pop up, or moving from cleveland to LA is really slow. Anyone have any solutions or ideas? Thanks

Comment: har many overlay objects have you got?

Comment: Hide the items between your touch operations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If an overlay is out of the screen you dont have to draw it. Make a rect object from the mapprojection (lefttop and rightbottom corner) and i think the method is called contains(x,y);

That may improve the performance :P

If you have many overlays at one point or really close together, just draw one.

Theres some samplecode :P

> ```
>   Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
>
>   for(int i = 0; i < your_locations.length; i++){
>       Point out = new Point();
>       mapView.getProjection().toPixels(your_locations[i], out);
>
>       if(rect.contains(out.x, out.y)){
>           //Draw it!
>       }
>   }
> ```